# SQL Display Case with 0 Records

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

OK I have a Statement Like this:

```
select 
CASE    
    WHEN lm.location_name like 'HM%' THEN 'HMO'
    WHEN lm.location_name like 'LS%' or lm.location_name = 'R' THEN 'LSR'
    WHEN lm.location_name like 'SD%' or lm.location_name like 'St%' THEN 'SSO'
    WHEN lm.location_name like 'ME%' THEN 'MV'
END as Office, 
CASE County
    WHEN '1' THEN 'A'
    WHEN '2' THEN 'B'
    WHEN '3' THEN 'B'
    WHEN '4' THEN 'C'
ELSE p.COUNTY END as County,
COUNT(*) as [Count]
from CTE as a
join location_mstr as lm
    on lm.location_id = a.location_id
join person as p
    on p.person_id = a.person_id
where 
ROW = 1
and CONVERT(datetime,a.date) >= CONVERT(datetime,'2015-04-01')
and CONVERT(datetime,a.date) <DATEADD(day,1,CONVERT(datetime,'2015-04-30'))
group by 
CASE    
    WHEN lm.location_name like 'HM%' THEN 'HMO'
    WHEN lm.location_name like 'LS%' or lm.location_name = 'R' THEN 'LSR'
    WHEN lm.location_name like 'SD%' or lm.location_name like 'St%' THEN 'SSO'
    WHEN lm.location_name like 'ME%' THEN 'MV'
END,
CASE County
    WHEN '1' THEN 'A'
    WHEN '2' THEN 'B'
    WHEN '3' THEN 'B'
    WHEN '4' THEN 'C'
ELSE p.COUNTY END
order by Office
```

Which gives me the proper results. However is it possible to have the location name or county appear if they have zero results.

For example if the combination of HMO office and B county have no results still appear as HMO | B | 0 rather than not at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark. I could probably give a better query if structure and data from CTE, location_mstr and person tables were available.

Overall, with the all_office_county CTE, we are extracting all possible combinations of office and county. We then take that as the primary dataset and left join with the results you have successfully obtained in your query. Wherever we find no match, we use a 0 for count.

```
with all_office_county as 
(
select
    distinct 
    CASE    
        WHEN lm.location_name like 'HM%' THEN 'HMO'
        WHEN lm.location_name like 'LS%' or lm.location_name = 'R' THEN 'LSR'
        WHEN lm.location_name like 'SD%' or lm.location_name like 'St%' THEN 'SSO'
        WHEN lm.location_name like 'ME%' THEN 'MV'
    END as Office,
    CASE County
        WHEN '1' THEN 'A'
        WHEN '2' THEN 'B'
        WHEN '3' THEN 'B'
        WHEN '4' THEN 'C'
    ELSE p.COUNTY END as County
from CTE a
left join location_mstr as lm on lm.location_id = a.location_id
left join person as p p.person_id = a.person_id
),

main as (
select 
CASE    
    WHEN lm.location_name like 'HM%' THEN 'HMO'
    WHEN lm.location_name like 'LS%' or lm.location_name = 'R' THEN 'LSR'
    WHEN lm.location_name like 'SD%' or lm.location_name like 'St%' THEN 'SSO'
    WHEN lm.location_name like 'ME%' THEN 'MV'
END as Office, 
CASE County
    WHEN '1' THEN 'A'
    WHEN '2' THEN 'B'
    WHEN '3' THEN 'B'
    WHEN '4' THEN 'C'
ELSE p.COUNTY END as County,
COUNT(*) as [Count]
from CTE as a
join location_mstr as lm
    on lm.location_id = a.location_id
join person as p
    on p.person_id = a.person_id
where 
ROW = 1
and CONVERT(datetime,a.date) >= CONVERT(datetime,'2015-04-01')
and CONVERT(datetime,a.date) <DATEADD(day,1,CONVERT(datetime,'2015-04-30'))
group by 
CASE    
    WHEN lm.location_name like 'HM%' THEN 'HMO'
    WHEN lm.location_name like 'LS%' or lm.location_name = 'R' THEN 'LSR'
    WHEN lm.location_name like 'SD%' or lm.location_name like 'St%' THEN 'SSO'
    WHEN lm.location_name like 'ME%' THEN 'MV'
END,
CASE County
    WHEN '1' THEN 'A'
    WHEN '2' THEN 'B'
    WHEN '3' THEN 'B'
    WHEN '4' THEN 'C'
ELSE p.COUNTY END
order by Office
)

select aoc.office, aoc.county, coalesce(m.[Count], 0)
from all_office_county aoc
left join main m on aoc.office = m.office and aoc.county = m.county
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `CTE` containing all possible results. Then `LEFT JOIN` your query to this `CTE`:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT x.o, y.c
   FROM (VALUES ('HMO'), ('LSR'), ('SSO')) AS x(o)
   CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('A'), ('B'), ('C')) AS y(c)
)
SELECT t1.o AS Office, t2.c AS County, COALESCE(t2.[Count], 0) AS [Count] 
FROM CTE AS t1
LEFT JOIN ( ... your query here ...) AS t2 
ON t1.o = t2.Office AND t1.c = t2.County
```

If a specific combination of office and county, e.g.`('HMO', 'B')`, has no results, then `t2.[Count]` is `NULL` in the above query and `0` is returned by the use of `COALESCE`.